# CSS inline divs using media queries to make responsive

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
.wrap div {
    border: 1px solid #f36f25;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
.clear:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    div.wrap div {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

which I'm using to display divs inline and using media queries, to make them responsive.

As the screen gets smaller, the 3rd div displays underneath the others, how can I make it fully responsive so that they all display underneath each other at the same time.

I would also like all 3 to be `width: 100%;` if the screen is too wide they display more of the left side than the centre.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/2/

I would also like to display 3 divs inline, then under those 3, one div under the first and then a larger div to fit under the second two divs. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/4/

use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
div.wrap div {
  border: 1px solid #f36f25;
  width: 29%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  div.wrap div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>testing 1</div>
  <div>testing 2</div>
  <div>testing 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i still want the text aligned left, not centre though, also can you check my update please for display two divs below these three

Comment: done only need to add `text-align: left;` for `div.wrap div` @user2710234

Comment: thanks - they seem to be displaying at different heights on my page

Comment: can i make them all the same height? as they all have different content inside

Comment: they are of the same size `40px` check in chrome using web inspector

Comment: but if they each have different content in - check this http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/5/

Comment: you will need to give fixed height and set it overflow hidden

Comment: they are still not displaying inline with a fixed height - check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/6/

Comment: great thanks - and how would i add two divs below? one div being the width of two of the above?

Answer (score 0):

You want them to be in 3 columns when its in large screen? if so, then your margin is causing it to drop underneath.

drop down the margin by 5px.

```
.wrap div {
    border: 1px solid #f36f25;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8k16vts/1/

Comment: they still display more left than centre though

Comment: huh? can you explain that in a better way?

Comment: i would like all 3 divs to display total of 100% in width across the page. as the screen gets wider, all 3 divs are displaying more left with a larger gap to the right of the 3rd div. see my update too